# Date format from mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to change date which is in the format mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd.
for example if date is 07/2015 then i need it to be as 2015-07-01

Comment: do you have that date as `string` or `date` ?

Comment: Dates don't have a format-  they are just data.  Where are you seeing the mm/yyyy format?

Comment: i am having date as string.   I need to do using stored procedure

Answer (score 2):

### SQL Server 2005 and onwards

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(7) = '07/2015'

SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@Date, 4) + LEFT(@Date,2) + '01' AS DATE)

RESULT:  2015-07-01
```

### SQL Server 2012 and onwards

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(7) = '07/2015'


SELECT DATEFROMPARTS( RIGHT(@Date, 4), LEFT(@Date,2), 1 )

RESULT:  2015-07-01
```